# How can I directly link to a TeamSpeak server on my website?

Tags: teamspeak

I am playing a lot of League of Legends at the moment, and what I don't like is the lack of voice communication in it. I want to be able to get people to my server without having to have too much hassle.

Here is what I plan to do:

1. Point people to a website I make. There should be the details to connect (password, etc) if people want to enter by themselves.
2. If people want to connect faster, have them click some kind of a link that should do the connecting for them.

Is it possible to host bookmarks that connects to to a TeamSpeak server with password and channel, or do I need to script this?

I want to really lower the barrier of people connecting, so the easier the better.

Comment: I realize this question is pretty old, but this question doesn't really have anything to do with video games. It's a question about a website and teamspeak, which happen to be common enough resources for video gamers, but neither of those things are video games.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just not about video games.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for help with software, and not a game.

Comment: @TimmyJim From Help Center: "If your question generally covers things such as … game-specific hardware and _utilities_ …then you are in the right place to ask your question!" From teamspeak.com: "TeamSpeak 3 offers the ideal voice communication _tool_ for online _gaming_, ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [TeamSpeak 3 FAQ](http://www.teamspeak.com/?page=faq&cat=client&rate=46#howto_connect_via_browser), this can be done.

> Complete format:
>
> ```
> ts3server://ts3.hoster.com?port=9987&nickname=UserNickname
> &password=serverPassword&channel=MyDefaultChannel&cid=channelID
> &channelpassword=defaultChannelPassword&token=TokenKey
> &addbookmark=MyBookMarkLabel
> ```
>
> Please keep in mind that if you use "`cid=channelID`", the parameter
>   "`channel=MyDefaultChannel`" will be ignored.
>
> Parameters are optional. In most cases, specifiying the host and port
>   should be sufficient. Nicknames usually should not be specified, leave
>   this to be configured by the users in the client.
>
> So a common URL would look like this:
>
> ```
> ts3server://ts3.hoster.com?port=9987
> ```
>
> Example for a complete HTML link:
>
> ```
> <a href="ts3server://ts3.hoster.com?port=9987">Click to connect to my
> ```
>
> server

For reference, this is how it used to be (and how it should still work for Teamspeak 2):

> Another way to connect to a server with the TeamSpeak Windows client
>   is via a webbrowser. The way to do it is as follows:
>
> ```
> teamspeak://{server_address}:{port}
> ```
>
> The parameters in the link are "`nickname`", "`loginname`", "`password`",
>   "`channel`", "`subchannel`", "`channelpassword`" and should be separated by
>   "`?`". TeamSpeak will start up automatically and log you in according to
>   the parameters given. Note that you do not have to enter all this
>   information if you just want to connect to a server via your
>   webbrowser. Just the IP address and port will do to log in to a server
>   as a guest.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> teamspeak://voice.teamspeak.org?nickname=WebGuest?channel=Talk
> ```

Comment: Additionally, I'm always shocked at how many voip server admins don't set up DNS names for their servers.  It's much easier to remember "voip.myclan.com" than an IP address.

Comment: @tarrasch Can you confirm that this works with TS3 as well?  I couldn't find any such confirmation on their FAQ

Comment: actually, it's ts3server://IP:port

Comment: Just to let you all know: ts3server://voice.teamspeak.org?nickname=WebGuest&channel=TalkChannel is the new way to do it. The only change being that it's "ts3server" not "teamspeak" at the beginning. This is correct as of 31st September 2013 when I found out :)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate such link in TeamSpeak 3 client.

Click `Tools > Invite Buddy`.

[image: Invite Buddy]

You can generate `ts3server://` URLs, `http://` URLs and HTML snippets. You can include your current channel or not.

[image: Invite Buddy Dialog]

**Note:** `ts3server://` URLs don't seem to be clickable in common instant messaging applications. In my experience, `http://` invite links are more bullet-proof. They do create an intermediate step (TeamSpeak is launched by a web landing page), but it's quick and non-problematic in practice.

Answer (score 0):

9987 is the default port so `?port=9987` is not required.
Only required if not default port

You can also connect using this url:
`ts3server://{site_url_or_ip}:{port}`